# Datatables show warning when deleting rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

In order to delete selected rows from an instance of Datatables, I can use:

```
var rows = table
    .rows( '.selected' )
    .remove()
    .draw();
```

However, I would also like to display a warning message to the user, like this:

```
var rows = table
    .rows( '.selected' )
    .showWarning('Are you sure you want to delete the selected rows?')
    .remove()
    .draw();
```

How can I display a warning to the user before deleting rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`confirm()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) as shown below:

```
if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the selected rows?')){
   var rows = table
      .rows( '.selected' )
      .remove()
      .draw();
}
```